# Conversion of large .csv file to .prn (around 3.5 GB) in Ubuntu using bash

Tags: excel, bash, csv, ubuntu, awk

I have a .csv file which is very large and has size about 3.5 GB, as I am dealing with big data and I need to convert this file to .prn file which seperates the columns with space delimiter.

Here is the sample input values in the file -

> **UNT**,Gujarat,84716050,25669.69,UNITS,"QX-870, IND BARCODE SCANNER, SW RSTR,LD,SRL+ETHNT S/N.:3402030.
>   FIS-0870-1004G.",INAMD4,M,2015-05-01,Ahmedabad,Import,MALAYSIA,1,274
>
> **UNT**,Gujarat,84716050,25669.69,UNITS,"QX-870, IND BARCODE SCANNER, SW RSTR,LD,SRL+ETHNT S/N.:3405176.
>   FIS-0870-1004G.",INAMD4,M,2015-05-01,Ahmedabad,Import,MALAYSIA,1,275
>
> **UNT**,Gujarat,84716050,25669.69,UNITS,"QX-870, IND BARCODE SCANNER, SW RSTR,LD,SRL+ETHNT S/N.:3405181.
>   FIS-0870-1004G.",INAMD4,M,2015-05-01,Ahmedabad,Import,MALAYSIA,1,276
>
> **KGS**,Gujarat,29213090,187897.88,KILOGRAMS,MEMANTINE HYDROCHLORIDE. BATCH NO. 134614003,INAMD4,W,2015-05-01,Ahmedabad,Import,ITALY,5,277

Now here if you look closely each division is a row of the file and you can also observe that each of the cell is seperated by comma. But we can also observe that in row 1 - "QX-870, IND BARCODE SCANNER, SW RSTR,LD,SRL+ETHNT S/N.:3402030. FIS-0870-1004G." contains several commas. So, if I will use comma(,) as a delimiter then I will end up seperating "QX-870" and "IND BARCODE SCANNER" and "SW RSTR" and "LD" and "SRL+ETHNT S/N.:3402030. FIS-0870-1004G." , which I don't want. So, I browse through the internet and found out that we can can change the format of the file using Microsoft Excel by saving the file in a different format(which I choose .prn format which solved my problem) but this great tool cannot convert bigger files(3.5 GB) so, I want my output something like this i.e row no. 1 on line 1, row no. 2 pn line 2 respectively.

> **UNT**    Gujarat    84716050    25669.69    UNITS    "QX-870, IND
>   BARCODE SCANNER, SW RSTR,LD,SRL+ETHNT S/N.:3402030. FIS-0870-1004G."
>   INAMD4    M    2015-05-01    Ahmedabad    Import    MALAYSIA    1
>   274
>
> **UNT**    Gujarat    84716050    25669.69    UNITS    "QX-870, IND
>   BARCODE SCANNER, SW RSTR,LD,SRL+ETHNT S/N.:3405176. FIS-0870-1004G."
>   INAMD4    M    2015-05-01    Ahmedabad    Import    MALAYSIA    1
>   275
>
> **UNT**    Gujarat    84716050    25669.69    UNITS    "QX-870, IND
>   BARCODE SCANNER, SW RSTR,LD,SRL+ETHNT S/N.:3405181. FIS-0870-1004G."
>   INAMD4    M    2015-05-01    Ahmedabad    Import    MALAYSIA    1
>   276
>
> **KGS**    Gujarat    29213090    187897.88    KILOGRAMS    MEMANTINE
>   HYDROCHLORIDE. BATCH NO. 134614003    INAMD4    W    2015-05-01
>   Ahmedabad    Import    ITALY    5    277

Comment: Instead of adding images, please add text sample data and output.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added the data

Comment: Can I assume that your objective is to print this huge csv file (formatted column-wise)?

Comment: Assuming you want to print your huge comma-separated .csv to a tab-spaced file, you can do it with awk as `awk '{$1=$1}1' FS="," OFS=" " input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: I want either of these two things- 
1) Either convert csv file into prn file with every cell left aligned or. 
2) replace the comma(,) delimiter by a tab delimiter because I have many cells with with comma(,) in between them.

Comment: Inian will your awk code handle the cells with comma in between them and not replace that comma with a tab??

Comment: Your various typed text formats don't seem to match. So, I am going to take the image shot showing the csv file (putty) as the correct one. You are showing chopped up column values in the image shot for prn file (Look at columns 2, 3,4). Is that what you want to be printed? If so, can you decide on the widths for those columns?

Comment: The following will replace commas that are separators with tabs, not commas between double-quotes: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) gsub(/,/,"\t",$i)}1' infile.csv > outfile.tsv`

Comment: Post your sample input and expected output as text files with their real delimiters. Right now you have a bunch of images we can't test a solution against and the only real text file you've posted as a sample of your input CSV file doesn't have any commas on most lines so it doesn't appear to be a CSV file at all. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can start to help you.

Comment: Fix your samples. Use the editors `{}` button to format them so we can copy/paste them to test against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question as you didn't provide sample input/output we could test against but it SOUNDS like all you're trying to do is this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split("7 10 15 12 4",w)
    FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]*\""
}
{
    gsub(/""/,RS)
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        gsub(/"/,"",$i)
        gsub(RS,"\"",$i)
        printf "<%-*s>", w[i], substr($i,1,w[i])
    }
    print ""
}

$ cat file
abcde,"ab,c,de","ab ""c"" de","a,""b"",c",ab
abcdefghi,"xyab,c,de","xyzab ""c"" de",abc,abcdefg

$ awk -f tst.awk file
<abcde  ><ab,c,de   ><ab "c" de      ><a,"b",c     ><ab  >
<abcdefg><xyab,c,de ><xyzab "c" de   ><abc         ><abcd>
```

Obviously I added the `<` and `>` around each field just to make it clear where each field starts/ends, you'd remove that for your real application and I'm creating the array `w` to hold specific widths for each field as idk where you get that from otherwise.

The above uses GNU awk for FPAT, with other awks it'd be a while(match()) loop.

Comment: Please wait I am posting my real input/output file sample data. Thank you for reply.

Comment: Do post your sample input/output but I'm not going to wait around and re-test with it. Just test my solution against it and let me know if it does or doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @EdMorton, Good one. I will look it over.

Comment: @EdMorton, I interpreted the fields to be: _<2> <1.7 Cubic Foot Compact "Cube" Office Refrigrators> <Barry French> <293> <457.81> <208.16> <68.02> <Nunavut> <Appliances> <0.58>_. You seem to be splitting the embedded commas as well. If that is what OP wanted, Ok.

Comment: I have no idea. The current question now has completely different sample input/output from before, formatted differently and apparently now with blank lines between data lines and maybe multi-line records..... idk.... it's a moving target!

Comment: @EdMorton, I wrote down the requirements from the images he provided. I didn't rely on his text-formatting (which seemed to have been affected by formatting on SO). His fields are, sometimes, double-quoted; sometimes, have embedded double-quoted strings inside (which are escaped with double-quotes); sometimes, have embedded commas.

Comment: Ed thank you very much for your answer I have really not understood your script properly but your script worked fine. Can you suggest me some tutorials from where I can learn awk from scratch.

Comment: @EdMorton, Just as clarification, I added a sample run in my answer showing what the initial data was. I am not a avid awk user; I had tried for a while with awk; gave up;  before heading over to Perl based solution. So, I was puzzled with your solution (which tokenized on embedded commas). On hindsight, it makes sense. You and I were working on two different problems.

Answer (score 1):

I found it difficult to do it in awk. So, I did it in Perl. Feel free to use it, if it suits your needs.

`1. A Column is protected with double quotes when it embeds a comma
   + Column could be "A Cube, Office"
2. A Column could have embedded double quotes. 
   + Column could be "A ""Cube"" Office"
   + Column could be """Cube"" Office"
   + Column could be "Cube ""Office"""
   + Column could be """Cube Office"""`

Try this following perl code. It turns lines into pipe-separated fields. If you are satisfied, you can turn it into tab-separated fields, and possibly chop columns to fixed width for printing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

# read next line
while (my $line=<>) {    
   # remove new line character from the end of line
   chomp($line);
   # protect double-quotes using alarm-bell-quotes
   $line=~s/["]["]([^"]*)["]["]/\a$1\a/g;

   # $out holds the processed columns
   my $out="";    
   while (1) {    
      my $matched=0;
      # Extract a double-quoted column    
      if ($line=~s/^["](.*?)["][,]//) { $out="$out$1|"; $matched=1; }
      # Extract a non-double-quoted column
      if ($line=~s/^([^",]*?)[,]//) { $out="$out$1|"; $matched=1; }    
      # If no more columns, break loop
      last if (!$matched);
   }

   # Put back the double-quotes (by replacing alarm-bells)
   $out=~s/\a/"/g;
   print "$out\n";    
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ cat data1
2,"1.7 Cubic Foot Compact ""Cube"" Office Refrigrators",Barry French,293,457.81,208.16,68.02,Nunavut,Appliances,0.58,
3,"1.7 Cubic, Foot Compact, Cube, Office Refrigrators",Barry French,293,457.81,208.16,68.02,Nunavut,Appliances,0.58,
3,"1.7 Cubic, Foot Compact, ""Cube"", Office Refrigrators",Barry French,293,457.81,208.16,68.02,Nunavut,Appliances,0.58,


$ cat data1 | ./3.pl
2|1.7 Cubic Foot Compact "Cube" Office Refrigrators|Barry French|293|457.81|208.16|68.02|Nunavut|Appliances|0.58|
3|1.7 Cubic, Foot Compact, Cube, Office Refrigrators|Barry French|293|457.81|208.16|68.02|Nunavut|Appliances|0.58|
3|1.7 Cubic, Foot Compact, "Cube", Office Refrigrators|Barry French|293|457.81|208.16|68.02|Nunavut|Appliances|0.58|
```

Comment: `This is too cumbersome to be done in awk.` - absolute nonsense.

Comment: Thanks blackpen for your answer but I don't have any idea about perl.

Comment: @shivamgupta It sounds like it doesn't address your problem anyway, it just changes `,`s between fields to `|`s between fields so then you have to worry about `|`s within fields instead of worrying about `,`s within fields, and it assumes there's no `\a` characters in your input file and it doesn't address your output field widths. So it changes part of your problem and creates a new problem for you but doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Yes I feel the same.

Comment: @EdMorton, Feel free to add a solution if you can. That would educate me as well. I have seen you write some nice awk scripts as I recollect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format a comma separated file (CSV), without changing its content (except the comma delimiter), you may use the following command:

```
column -t -s, file.csv
```

The `column` command will determine the maximum length of each column in your CSV file and pad with space to align your data.

Comment: Thanks @oliv for your answer but column command doesn't solve the issue. It replaces the comma within a cell with a tab and seperates each cell with a space. Here, is the out that column command gives-  below ---- -1  "Eldon Base for stackable storage shelf                  platinum"  "ceve  ve                                                                                        ve"  3       -213.25  38.94  35       Nunavut     Storage & Organization  0.8